# Differentiating $3\int_0^te^uf(u)du$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I differentiate this function - $$3\int_0^te^uf(u)du$$

Does differentiation cancel out the integration? And do I then have

$$3(e^tf(t) - e^0f(0))$$

I am not sure if that is right and I'm not sure of the step by step process for 'cancelling' the integration?

Comment: The [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) states that $$ \frac{d}{dt} \left(3 \int_0^t e^u f(u) du\right) = 3 e^t f(t)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general
$$\frac{d}{{dt}}\int_{u(t)}^{v(t)}f(x,t)dx = \int_{u(t)}^{v(t)}{\frac{\partial}{{\partial t}}f(x,t)dx + f(v(t),t)v'(t)} - f(u(t),t)u'(t).$$
When $u$ and $v$ are constants, this simplifies to
$$\frac{d}{{dt}}\int_{u}^{v}f(x,t)dx = \int_u^v{\frac{\partial}{{\partial t}}f(x,t)dx}.$$
This very powerful rule is known as Leibniz rule. This is how use differentiate integrals. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \int_0^t F(x) dx\right) = F(t)$$ Hence, the answer is just $$3 e^t f(t)$$

Comment: What about evaluating it at 0? Are you not leaving out the term $e^0f(0)$?

Comment: @css:  No, because it does not depend upon $t$, so its derivative is zero.

Comment: @csss you have the derivative $\frac{df(0)}{dt}$, which is derivative of a constant, which is 0.